# Extract JSON inside JSON in CN1

Tags: codenameone

My app receives JSON responses from an API. When it arrives, the app uses the JSONParser class to get a result as a Map:

```
JSONParser jp = new JSONParser();
Map <String, Object> result = jp.parseJSON(new InputStreamReader(input, "UTF-8"));
```

The "result" contains 2 values. First a URL that I can get using the key "url":

```
String url = result.get("url");
```

And second, another set of data which is in JSON format and I get using the key "eager". I tried to extract it to a Map:

```
java.util.List<Map<String, Object>> eager =  (java.util.List<Map<String, Object>>) result.get("eager");
```

The resulting Map does not behave like a Map, so I passed the whole eager Map to a String, just to check the content and I noticed that the data is inside brackets, like this:

```
[{item1=x, item2=x,.....itemN=x}]
```

**Question:**
How can I get the data as a JSON object?

Comment: You need to place a breakpoint on the line after the parsing and use the debugger variable inspector tool to understand the data structure.

Answer (score 2):

You parse your result String as a List. What happend if you try to get "data" like this ?

```
java.util.List<Map<String, Object>> newResult =  (java.util.List<Map<String, Object>>) result.get(0);
```

Comment: No, it didn't work. I edited my question to be more specific.

Comment: I got it. Your answer was very close. I had to iterate one more time. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the key "root" not "data" to get your list.

Comment: The real name of the key is "eager". I edited my question. That key does give me the data, but inside the brackets. I will try to use "root" to the "eager" Map

Comment: I applied "toArray()" to the eager Map. Now I can get position 0 of that array and I get the data in {} instead of [{}]. How can I turn that into a Map or Hashtable?.

Answer (score 1):

"result" is a Map.
"eager" is a List of Maps.

You need to get the first position of the eager Map in order to get the Map with the data:

```
Map <String, Object> result = jp.parseJSON(new InputStreamReader(input, "UTF-8"));

java.util.List<Map<String, Object>> eager =  (java.util.List<Map<String, Object>>) result.get("eager");

Map<String, Object> eagerMap =  (Map<String, Object>) eager.get(0);
```